# PHP for loop remaining values

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

Is there any more professional or easier way to achieve a PHP for loop, that also iterates when there are only remaining elements? (In the current example: 1126)

```
<?php
$max = 11126;
$step = 2000;

for ($i = 0; $i < $max; null) {
    if ($max - $i > $step) {
        $i += $step;
    } else {
        $i += $max - $i;
    }

    echo($i . ", ");
}

?>
```

Outpts:

```
2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000, 11126,
```

...which is correct, but looks like too much of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as the loop already has the continue decision, there is always something to output because `$max` is already the exit:

Example/[Demo](https://eval.in/46075):

```
for ($i = 0;  ($i += $step) < $max;) {
    echo $i, ', ';
}
echo $max;
```

Program Output:

```
2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000, 11126
```

All what follows is just some older playing around... .

---

To create exactly your output (with the comma at the end) you can use a different kind of loop that checks to loop after it looped:

Example/[Demo](https://eval.in/46064):

```
$i = 0;
do {
   $i += $step;
   echo min($i, $max), ', ';
} while ($i < $max);
```

Program Output:

```
2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000, 11126,
```

---

Or why not a `for` loop with having the output in the pre-condition?

Example/[Demo](https://eval.in/46069):

```
for (
   $i = 0;
   printf('%d, ', min($i += $step, $max)) 
   && ($i < $max);
);
```

Program Output:

```
2000, 4000, 6000, 8000, 10000, 11126,
```

Comment: This answer clearly lacks jquery. No wonder you got downvoted!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if my solution is more 'professionnal' but it gives you a different one at least ;)

```
$showSteps = function($max, $step) {
    $arr = array();
    for ($i = $step; $i <= $max; $i = $i + $step) {
        $arr[] = $i;
    }

    if (($max % $step) > 0) {
        $arr[] = intval($max/$step) * $step + $max % $step;
    }

    print implode(', ', $arr);    
};

$showSteps(11126, 2000);
```