# PHP - duplicate value

Tags: php, loops

I had this code

```
$loop ="5";
$value = "1";
```

how to insert value to db like this 1:1:1:1:1 (where loop have 5)

thanks

Comment: Look up `array_fill`, and `implode`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP for loop remaining values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18540260/php-for-loop-remaining-values)

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this. http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php, http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Comment: my case not same @adam moffat

Comment: right, like that, thanks @chris85

Comment: Use `array_fill()` and `implode()`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
string $val_for_Db = "";
for ($i=0;$i<$loop;$i++) {
$val_for_Db = $val_for_Db."".$value.":";
}
$val_for_Db = substr($val_for_Db ,-1);
```

Now insert $val_for_Db to database.

Comment: Please **avoid** answering **bad** questions

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your new but please take the time to read through this in order to ask better questions. We do not write code for you we help with specific problems. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask